# SQLite3 Find Average Value for

Tags: sql, sqlite, average

I am learning SQlite3 right now and I have three tables:

```
FROM DIRECTOR dr,
```

This produces only the First director (first directorId 'DId') and then it gives the average of ALL movie budgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, dirId, AVG(budget)
FROM DIRECTOR, DIRECTED, MOVIE
WHERE dir.DId = dir.DirectorId   AND
dir.MovieIdentity= mov.MovieIdentity
group by MovieIdentity
```

Comment: That's arranged the ID's and Names perfectly! But, The AVG(budget) is giving the same value for each: 2415740.6666667 in each AVG(budget) result.

Comment: "no such column dir.name" is what outputs :/